# What happens to the alpha channel in different blend modes

Tags: gimp, blend-modes

I have a question about how the resulting alpha is computed for different blend modes in gimp.

The manual [1] describes the color channels, but not how the opacity is processed (I am also sort of interested in a rationale).

[1] https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html

Comment: I think this is a question for the GIMP development community, not a graphic design community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all but specific modes (Normal, Dissolve...), the alpha of the result is the alpha of the bottom layer(*). And when it comes to the alpha of the top layer, these two methods produce the same result:

Method #1: Apply Top (blend) layer at x% opacity

Method #2: Apply Top (blend) layer at 100% opacity, get the result (`Layer>New from visible`), hide the "blend" layer and  set the result layer to x% opacity.

(*) Within a layer group...  because layer groups act like parentheses in an equation, the blend mode of a layer only applies to the layers below it in the same group.

Comment: Yes, with exception of displve it works like this.